# How to detect objects on the canvas with click event

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas, mouseevent

Hi I am using a hashmap that allows me to efficiently detect objects in the given coordinates. However it is working perfectly , the problem lies with using the mouse to gather the position of the mouse within the canvas down to the pixel. I have been using the offsetX and offsetY methods for the event to gather some offset but it seems there is an offset I am unaware of and may have something to do with either:

1.using scaling on the canvas , Note: ive tried to fix this by division of the renderscale, this works with everything else so should be fine here.

2. mouseoffset is not accounting for parts of the page or is missing pixels at a low level (maybe 20) but divided by the render scale thats massive.

3.I am using a cartesian coordinate system to simplify things for the future , so the game map is in cartesian and may have to do with the problem.

I will not be supplying all the code because it is allot of work to go through it all so i will supply the following :

1. the html/css canvas code

   ```
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <title> Game</title>
   </head>
   <body onload="jsEngine = new JsEngine(24, 24, .1); " >


   <div class ="wrapper">
       <canvas  id="canvas" width="1920" height="1080"></canvas>
   </div>


   <style>



       .wrapper { 
       position: relative;
       width: auto;
       height: 900px;
       }


       .wrapper   canvas {
          position: absolute;
          left: 90px;
          top: 50px;
          padding-left: 0;
          padding-right: 0;
          margin-left: auto;
          margin-right: auto;
          display: block;
          width: 90%;
          height: 90%;}

      .GUI{
          top: -315px;
          left: -302px;
          position: absolute;
          width: 300px;
          height: 300px;
          background-color: cadetblue;

          opacity: .5;
          word-wrap: break-word;}



       img{
            image-rendering: optimize-contrast;
   }
   </style>


   <div id = GUI class = "GUI"></div>







       <!-- Libraries -->
   <script src="../myapi/JSONE.js"></script>
   <script src="../myapi/engine/SpacialHash.js"></script>






   </body>
   </html>
   ```

2.the javascript click function

```
  //Click on objects
let onClick = function(event){
    let canvas_ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
let canvasOffsetX = canvas_ctx.canvas.width/2;
let canvasOffsetY = canvas_ctx.canvas.height/2;
let mousePosX = event.clientX;
let mousePosY = event.clientY;

    let mouseX =jsEngine.cameraFocus.x-canvasOffsetX/jsEngine.renderScale+(mousePosX)/jsEngine.renderScale;
    let mouseY = jsEngine.cameraFocus.y+(canvasOffsetY)/jsEngine.renderScale+((-mousePosY)/jsEngine.renderScale);
    console.log("sum to",mouseX,mouseY);





//My hashMap to place the mouse coordinates on the game map
    let clickPosition = hm.find({x:mouseX,y:mouseY,width:1,height:1});



    if(clickPosition.length===1){
        let gameObject = jsEngine.gameObjects[clickPosition[0].range.id];
        //console.log(gameObject.transform.x,gameObject.transform.y,mouseX,mouseY);
        let clickBox = {};
        let picture = gameObject.texture;
        guiCreateClickBox(clickBox,gameObject.id,1200,500,picture);

    }else if(clickPosition.length>1) {
        for (let i = 0; i < clickPosition.length; i++) {
            let gameObject = jsEngine.gameObjects[clickPosition[i].range.id];
            if (gameObject instanceof PlayerShip|| gameObject instanceof Bullet)
                continue;
            let clickBox = {};
            let picture = gameObject.texture;
            guiCreateClickBox(clickBox,gameObject.id,1200,500,picture);

            //console.log(gameObject.transform.x,gameObject.transform.y,mouseX,mouseY)

        }
    }
};

// Listeners
//Click on objects
document.getElementById("canvas").addEventListener("click", onClick);
```

3. the making of the map and scale :Note: this is done via onPreRender

   ```
   function drawBackground(canvas_ctx, renderScale, imageResource) {
   let img = imageResource.mapBackground;
   let mapWidth = 1000000;
   let mapHeight= 1000000;
   let zoom = 1;

   mapWidth *= renderScale / zoom;
   mapHeight *= renderScale / zoom;

   // Render the Background
   canvas_ctx.fillStyle = canvas_ctx.createPattern(img, 'repeat');
   canvas_ctx.scale(zoom, zoom);
   canvas_ctx.fillRect(-mapWidth / 2, - mapHeight / 2, mapWidth, mapHeight);

   //if (jsEngine.cameraFocus.x > 1000000) {}

   canvas_ctx.scale(1/zoom, 1/zoom);
   }
   ```
4. The rendering method used for playership

   ```
   renderGameObject(gameObject) {
   let x = gameObject.transform.x * this.renderScale;
   let y = -(gameObject.transform.y * this.renderScale);
   let rotation = Math.radians(gameObject.transform.rotation);
   let width = gameObject.transform.width;
   width *= this.renderScale;
   let height = gameObject.texture.height;
   height *= this.renderScale;

   // Render the gameObject
   this.canvas_ctx.translate(x, y);
   this.canvas_ctx.rotate(rotation);
   this.canvas_ctx.drawImage(gameObject.texture, 0, 0, width / this.renderScale, height / this.renderScale,  // Make sure the image is not cropped
       -width/2 ,         // X
       -height/2 ,        // Y
       width, height);     // width and height
   this.canvas_ctx.rotate(-rotation);
   this.canvas_ctx.translate(-x, -y);


   }
   ```

the issue to solve is to make it so that when you click on any given quadrant of the canvas it will return -+ for top left, -- bottom left , -+ topright, +- bottomright, as well as being applied to the render scale which at the moment is .1 so just divide your mouse and canvas coords like shown above and you should be able to get the same results.

Things to keep in mind :

1. the jsEngine.cameraFocus is set to the playerships x and y coordinates(which are set to the 0,0 posiiton on the map) (which are also in the middle of the ship)
2. the top left of the canvas is still 0,0 and ++ is still toward the bottom right so theoretically minusing half the canvas width/height then adding the offsets X and Y. this should be working but at my map coordinate -4000,-4000 i get ~-3620,-3295 and at +4000,+4000 I get 3500,3500. (The reason why the canvas 0,0 is not where the ship is , is to make the ship in the middle of the screen)

**If you have questions about anything based on code that needs to be supplied please ask via comment . Please note if you have problems with the format of the code supplied I have nothing to say about it . all I need is the click function working on the canvas model i set up in cartesian format.**

ps: jQuery is not a solution its a problem please use vanilla js.

Answer (score 0):

I found out why it was off , my canvas has a offset of 90 px and 50 px as well as the main problem that the canvas is only 90% of its origonal size (also in css). If anyone can give me help for how to adjust to these issues please reply in comment . until then I beleieve I have solved my own issue .